# Append an object to an array's value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What I'm trying to accomplish in php is the following:

```
$var->doSomething(['chris' => ['age' => 22], 'evan']);
```

I'm sending an array via a formData (not like the above question, obviously), and php reads the array perfectly like this:

```
$array = $_POST('arrayOfValues');
$var->doSomething($array);
```

The data on my js formdata is the following:

```
var array = ['chris', 'evan'];
var data = new FormData();
array.forEach(function(item){
                            data.append('arrayOfValues[]', item);
                        });
```

I have no idea how to accomplish it, an acquaintance told me to try an object, but it didn't work (I dunno if I have to parse it somehow in php or js).
PD: JQuery or JS are accepted, but I'd prefer the latter for learning purposes

Comment: `var data = new formData();` your console you be telling you this is an error.  The correct case is `FormData`

Comment: I guess `formData` is a class? where is this defined?

Comment: Sorry, the typo came from making the above example as simple as I could (it's not a copypaste from the actual code), I'm gonna edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formData creates only a set of key/values pairs representing form fields.
If you want to send complex objects to PHP you have to use JSON.

To create JSon objects use:

```
var myArrayObj = { ... };
var json = JSON.stringify( myArrayObject);
```

More information on json: http://www.json.org/js.html

So, in PHP, use:

```
var_dump(json_decode($json)); //where $json is your data from JS
```

Comment: i think OP wants to use a POPO (plain old php object) but is unsure of how to do that, i dont think this is related to json or a json object like you mentioned

Comment: Ohh, maybe. I was figuring out he was triyng to create a object in JS and sending to PHP. Like this: { 'chris' : { age : 22 }, 'evan' : { age : 30 } }

Comment: yes, i think so but op isn't replying so i guess he figured it out... zzz

Comment: Apologies, I was having dinner so sorry for the late reply. I'm going to have a look at @FelipeThomas 's answer and I'll mark it as accepted if it resolves the issue

Comment: OH, I forgot to mention that I'm using FormData because I'm sending a file along the data and that's why I'm not using json nor java objects to send the array to the server.

Comment: You can send JSON string (your object) inside a form field, it's not the best solution, but works. In PHP use json_decode on the POST data field, like this: $obj = json_decode($_POST['whatever']);

Comment: I shoved my head on docs according to your answer and it worked it was the one I was looking for, it was indeed, an object, now I'm struggling with the server-side method that's not accepting the object, but now that's not related to JavaScript, thanks for your answer

Comment: Managed to get it working perfectly, just had to add true to your json decode, edited your answer so people who runs into this specific problem can get the answer :)